# disable radmenu button from javascript that is called from the vb.net page load function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I am trying to make it that  `on page load` in the code behind, I disable a button in the radmenu using javascript

If I run my javascript in the console window in the browser to test then the button will disable. so that proofs that the JavaScript works.

the error is : cant find object - `$find('myRadMenu')`  and the name is correct, so it has something todo with when the radmenu is rendered so I tried a wrap my script in a document.ready  but that also won't work

```
'' not working with document.ready

'    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

'    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "test", "<script type='text/javascript'> $(document).ready(function(){$find('myRadMenu').findItemByText('MyButton').disable();}); </script>")

'    End Sub




Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "test", "<script type='text/javascript'> $find('myRadMenu').findItemByText('MyButton').disable(); </script>")

End Sub
```

Do you know how to disable a radmenu button from javascript that is called from the vb.net page load function.

It must be done this way as I have other javascript that needs to fire

Comment: try $find("<%=myRadMenu.ClientID%>")

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

JS

```
function DisabelMenu(MenuText) {
            setTimeout(function () { SetSettingAfterSometime(MenuText) }, 100);
        }

        function SetSettingAfterSometime(MenuText) {
            var menu = $find("<%=RadMenu1.ClientID%>");
            menu.findItemByText(MenuText).disable();
        }
```

CS

```
RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "test123", "DisabelMenu('test2');", true);
```

If you get the null then increase the timeout delay.

Comment: Without that it is not possible because you are trying to access the RadMenu before it completely rendered on browser/client site. i have set "0.1" second so it will execute to fast.  Other option is that when page is load first time at that please disable menu from server side and for second time you can achieve same this by client side.